# Pytube HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request, pytube

I was going to download youtube video so wrote  a code in python using **pytube** module.
I tried **pip install pytube** and **pip install pytube3** .
Only pytube3 worked for me .

```
from pytube import YouTube

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJ08IGp5ulA&t=23s'

yt = YouTube(url)

videos = yt.streams.all()

print(videos)
```

I used this code but got error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\utube\sunil.py", line 5, in <module>
    yt = YouTube(url)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 162, in prefetch
    self.watch_html = request.get(url=self.watch_url)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

So help me to fix this.

Comment: YouTube is unhappy about you making too many requests.

Comment: So How to make YouTube happy and make my work done ?

Comment: [Link to a third-party answer](https://medium.com/@emrebayram_71713/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-in-python-while-using-pytube-library-39c5eced838e).

Comment: @DYZ sometimes i get this error on some videos, but not on others. Why is this? (If I make a request to a different youtube video, it works fine)